# Understanding a test for divisibility by 9

Tags: elementary-number-theory

On page 32 of J.E Thompson’s *[Arithmetic for the practical man](http://hdl.handle.net/2027/mdp.39015053141936)*, he writes (emphasis added):

> Consider next divisibility by 9. Since 10=9+1, any number of 10’s equals the same number of 9’s plus the same number of 1’s. Since 100 = 99+1, any number of 100’s equals the same number of 99’s plus the same number of 1’s. […] Also 9, 99, 999, etc., are each multiples of 9. **Therefore, any number is some multiple of 9 plus the sum of its separate figures and so is divisible by 9 if the sum of its figures is.** That is
>
> (v) *If the sum of the separate figures of any number is divisible by 9, the number is divisible by 9.*
>
> As an example, take 7362. Here 7+3+6+2=18, which is divisible by 9. Therefore, 7362 is divisible by 9; the quotient is 818.

I think what he means in the boldface is that a number whose remainder is divisible by 9 after being subtracted by an appropriate amount of 9s/99s/999s is a multiple of 9? (E.g. if 3078 = 3×999 + 81, since 81 is divisible by 9 and 999 is divisible by 9 too, we deduce that 3078 is divisible by 9.)

I understand how (v) works but I don’t understand how he is able to get to the conclusion/rule stated in (v)?

Comment: Are you familiar with congruences or modular arithmetic? e.g. $\,10\equiv 1\pmod 9\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an example, consider the number 7513.  We have
\begin{eqnarray*}
7513&=&7\cdot1000+5\cdot100+1\cdot10+3\\
&=&7\cdot(999+1)+5\cdot(99+1)+1\cdot(9+1)+3\\
&=&(7\cdot999+5\cdot99+1\cdot9)+(7+5+1+3).
\end{eqnarray*}
Since 999, 99 and 9 are all multiples of 9, this means that 7513 and 7+5+1+3 differ by a multiple of 9.  Therefore, they will have the same remainder upon being divided by 9, so one will be a multiple of 9 just when the other is.  The rule works in the same way for all other positive whole numbers.

Comment: Thanks! The way you "split" up and "rearrange" the numbers helped me in understanding on how he arrived at (v).